# Как удалить из двумерного массива элементы с одинаковым свойством?

Tags: php, алгоритм

Есть массив:

```
array(
    'category 1' => array(
        array('name' => 'Криведка', 'data' => 111),
        array('name' => 'Стол', 'data' => 222),
        array('name' => 'Капибара', 'data' => 333),
    ),

    'category 2' => array(
        array('name' => 'Луна', 'data' => 444),
        array('name' => 'Скайп', 'data' => 111),
    )
)
```

В нем есть *категории*, в примере их 2, но может быть и больше.

Так вот, надо удалить массивы из категорий с одинаковой `data`

В данном случае повторяются эти:

```
array('name' => 'Криведка', 'data' => 111) // Из первой категории
array('name' => 'Скайп', 'data' => 111) // Из второй категории
```

Надо оставить только один, не важно из какой категории. Т.е. на выходе должно получится, допустим, так:

```
array(
    'category 1' => array(
        array('name' => 'Криведка', 'data' => 111),
        array('name' => 'Стол', 'data' => 222),
        array('name' => 'Капибара', 'data' => 333),
    ),

    'category 2' => array(
        array('name' => 'Луна', 'data' => 444)
    )
)
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: И где проблема?

Comment: @Visman Ясно же, что в "Криведке". ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$num = array();   // тут храним найденные номера
$new = array();   // а тут - новый массив
foreach($array as $key=>$item) {
    $new[$key] = 
        array_filter($item, 
                     function($v) use (&$num) {
                        if(in_array($v['data'], $num)) 
                           return false; 
                           else { $num[] = $v['data']; return true; }});
}

print_r($new);
```

Comment: Вот что вышло http://code.re/9s3

Comment: Он оборачивает каждую категорию в массив

Comment: @Fangog эту мелочь вы сами постарайтесь изменить. Вам подсказали хорошее решение.

Comment: Я поправил,но надеюсь, вы раньше справились :)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с вложенными "прогулками" по массиву (без явных циклов).
Во внутренней "прогулке" по каждой категории создаётся список ключей для удаления и массив уникальных данных.
На все изменяемые параметры ставим амперсанды.

```
$arr =
array(
    'category 1' => array(
        array('name' => 'Криведка', 'data' => 111),
        array('name' => 'Стол', 'data' => 222),
        array('name' => 'Капибара', 'data' => 333)
    ),

    'category 2' => array(
        array('name' => 'Луна', 'data' => 444),
        array('name' => 'Скайп', 'data' => 111)
    )
);

$all_data= array();

var_dump($arr);
array_walk($arr, function(&$cat) use(&$all_data){
    $key_del = array();
    array_walk($cat, function($item, $key) use(&$all_data, &$key_del){
        if(in_array($item["data"], $all_data)){
            array_push($key_del, $key);
        } else{
            array_push($all_data, $item["data"]);
        }
    });
    while (count($key_del)){
        unset($cat[array_pop($key_del)]);
    }
});
var_dump($arr);
var_dump($all_data);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  'category 1' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'Криведка' (length=16)
          'data' => int 111
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'Стол' (length=8)
          'data' => int 222
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'Капибара' (length=16)
          'data' => int 333
  'category 2' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'Луна' (length=8)
          'data' => int 444
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'Скайп' (length=10)
          'data' => int 111
array (size=2)
  'category 1' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'Криведка' (length=16)
          'data' => int 111
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'Стол' (length=8)
          'data' => int 222
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'Капибара' (length=16)
          'data' => int 333
  'category 2' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'Луна' (length=8)
          'data' => int 444
array (size=4)
  0 => int 111
  1 => int 222
  2 => int 333
  3 => int 444
```